# How to check the version of Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Linux and I want to know if I can check what version of angular-material am using. I'm using bower for installing/updating packages.

Comment: Check `bower_components/angular-material/bower.json` ?

Comment: Ow hey.. that was easy... thank you! (am new to composer/angular)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If installed with npm**

```
npm list @angular/material
```

**If installed with yarn**

```
yarn list @angular/material
```

**If installed with bower, as in OP case**

You can check out what version of *angular-material* you use by opening the following file:

```
bower_components/angular-material/bower.json
```

which will display something like that:

```
{
  "name": "angular-material",
  "version": "0.11.0",
  ...
}
```

Or as Matt pointed, use `bower list`, then lookup for *angular-material*.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as the bower.json file may show an approximate or minimum version number. To get your current version use `bower list`.

Comment: You are probably confusing with the user application *bower.json*, while I am referring to the *bower.json* of the installed package. The `bower list` command is indeed a solution, but guess what, under the hood it reads the *bower.json* of the installed packages.

Answer (score 20):

Looks like you can use `npm ls @angular/material` to tell you the exact version.

Answer (score 4):

if you have npm installed the following may help

```
npm angular/material -v
```

Comment: this gave me the version of npm! not angular.

Answer (score 3):

I normally use ng --version, this will list the version of everything I have installed

```
Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.26
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.26
@angular/cdk                               8.2.3
@angular/cli                               8.3.26
@angular/compiler-cli                      8.2.14
@angular/material                          8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.26
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.1.1
@schematics/angular                        8.3.26
@schematics/update                         0.803.26
rxjs                                       6.5.4
typescript                                 3.5.3
webpack                                    4.39.2
```

Answer (score 2):

To check the version of a bower package from the terminal, you can use `bower list` which will render a dependency tree like this one:

```
bower check-new     Checking for new versions of the project dependencies...
My App#0.0.1 C:\Development\my-app
├── angular#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
├─┬ angular-animate#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
│ └── angular#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
├─┬ angular-aria#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
│ └── angular#1.4.7
├─┬ angular-cookies#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
│ └── angular#1.4.7
├── angular-local-storage not installed
├─┬ angular-material#0.11.2 (latest is 1.0.5)
│ ├── angular#1.4.7 (1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4 available)
│ ├── angular-animate#1.4.7 (1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4 available)
│ └── angular-aria#1.4.7 (1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4 available)
├─┬ angular-resource#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
│ └── angular#1.4.7
└─┬ angular-sanitize#1.4.7 (latest is 1.5.1-build.4592+sha.c4e47e4)
  └── angular#1.4.7
```

In my example, `angular-material` is installed with version `0.11.2` (and I should update it to `1.0.5`).

To process this (and a lot more) information via a node script, for example in Jenkins, you can use the `--json` parameter: `bower list --json`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project, and open the following file:

```
node_modules/@angular/material/package.json
```

In this file, the ID contains the version installed for that project.

Comment: This question is answered very long ago. Why would this answer be better?